# Увеличение счётчика при зажатии

Tags: javascript, jquery

Сейчас нужно каждый раз нажимать для увеличения переменной. Как сделать, чтобы при зажатии переменная увеличивалась?

```
count=0;
$( document ).on( "click", "#btn", function() {
  count++;
  $("p").text(count);
});
```

Comment: использовать `keypress` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант использовать `setInterval`:

```js
var int = null;
var count = 0;
$("#btn").on('mousedown', function() {
  int = setInterval(function() {
    count++;
    $("p").text(count);
  }, 100);
}).on('mouseup mouseleave', function() {
  clearInterval(int);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click</button>
<p></p>
```

Comment: Супер только надо еще добавить к `mouseup` `mouseleave` , иначе если зажмете кнопку и отведете от нее курсор счетчик будет бесконечно накручивать и отпустить кнопку уже не получится

Comment: ..поддерживать touch-устройства, обернуть как jQuery-плагин и выложить на github, пожалуйста!

Comment: @redroid, Действительно, не учел этот момент. Исправил!

Comment: На мобилке не пашет.

Comment: плюсанул, но у меня на такое имя переменной - int - редактор жутко ругался!!))...

Comment: В этом варианте одинарной клик будет с задержкой, 100мс. Я поставил себе 200мс для более плавного изменения при удержании, а для одинарного клика добавил условие в цепочку .on('click', function() {...});

Answer (score 1):

Вариант с `requestAnimationFrame()` и ускорением перемотки по мере удержания. Надо ещё подумать над формулой для изменения задержки, чтобы поквадратичнее было : )

```js
var $btnInc = $('#btn-inc')
  ,$btnDec = $('#btn-dec')
  ,$out = $('#in-value')
  ,v = $out.val()
  ,maxDelay = 400
  ,delay = maxDelay
  ,minDelay = 100
  ,start
  ,action
;

function update(timestamp) {
  if(!start) start = timestamp;
  if(action  &&  (timestamp - start) >= delay) {
    start = timestamp;
    if( delay > minDelay  &&  (delay -= 20) <= minDelay) delay = minDelay;
    switch(action){
      case "inc": v++; break;
      case "dec": v--; break;
    }
    $out.val(v);
  }
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

$btnInc.on('mousedown', incOn);
$btnInc.on('mouseup mouseout', incdecOff);
$btnDec.on('mousedown', decOn);
$btnDec.on('mouseup mouseout', incdecOff);
$out.on('input', function(){ v = $out.val(); });

function incOn(){ action = "inc";}
function incdecOff(){action = undefined; delay = maxDelay;}
function decOn(){ action = "dec";}
  
window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn-dec">&ndash;</button>
<input id="in-value" value="0"/>
<button id="btn-inc">+</button>
```

Comment: Интересно,спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

А вот вариант с созданием jQuery плагина и навешиванием на любой элемент с произвольным заданием стартового счетчика + мобильные обработчики https://jsfiddle.net/2sr5s4vu/10/:

```
//создать jq плагин
$.fn.cc = function(i) {
  function counter() {
    var timeoutId;
    var el = $(this);
    var c = parseInt(i);
    var inerTxt = el.text();
    //действия
    var action = {
      '.min': "-",
      '.max': "+"
    };
    //доавить в контэйнер элементы
    el.empty().append("<div class='hold min'>-</div><div class='hold counter'></div><div class='hold max'>+</div>")
    var counter = el.find('.counter');
    counter.text(inerTxt + " " + c);
    //Добавить на кнопки +- бинды
    $.map(action, function(v, k) {
      el.find(k).on("touchstart mousedown", function() {
        timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
          //изменить значение счетчика в зависимости от действия
          c = eval(c + v + 1);
          counter.text(inerTxt + " " + c);
        }, 100);
      }).bind('touchend mouseup mouseleave', function() {
        clearTimeout(timeoutId);
      });
    });

  }
  //обойти все подходящие селекторы , навешать на них счетчики
  this.each(counter);
}

//создать несколько произвольных счетчиков с разными значениями
for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
  $(".list").append('<div id="cc' + i + '">hold down me!</div>');
  $("#cc" + i).cc(Math.random() * 10);
}
```